# RubyOnRails 3 on WHM (centOS)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, whm

I have server (centOS 5.5) and WHM installed. I installed  manually Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.0.4, Passenger 3.0.0.pre4 and passenger apache module, because mongrel doesn't work with WHM (cPanel) and Rails 3.

I have problem with passenger setup, because, I must to add 3 lines of code and vhost definition in httpd.conf file, bud WHM auto-generate this file and this doesn't work.

Did you have experience with Passenger and WHM? I need help to make this to work :|

Comment: I found this:http://jetpackweb.com/blog/2009/07/21/install-phusion-passenger-a-k-a-mod_rails-on-cpanel-server/ but I can't start server with passenger start. I get this error :( http://cl.ly/453x2O1g2z2e1y211E3Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem with this tutorial: http://jetpackweb.com/blog/2009/07/21/install-phusion-passenger-a-k-a-mod_rails-on-cpanel-server/